disabling yarn logs - dataproc cluster
I am trying to reduce the Class A operations on a gcs bucket which is being configured to store yarn and spark history logs.
This is costing us a lot. I disabled spark logs editing the spark-defaults.conf file.
for every spark job runs, it is adding yarn logs to the gcs bucket.

can I exclude below properties from yarn-site.xml
<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Enable remote logs aggregation to the default FS.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>gs://dataproc-temp-europe-north1-89560059592-dqicljms/d0decf20-21fd-4536-bbc4-5a4f829e49bf/yarn-logs</value>
    <description>
        The remote path, on the default FS, to store logs.
    </description>
</property>

Do I need to exclude both or yarn.log-aggregation-enable=false will work?
enabling them again will also work when we need them
Update: disabling and removing above code from yarn site xml did not help. I see yarn logs still being written to the gcs bucket.

Is creating a life cycle policy on the log bucket an option to remove the old logs? You might see issues for troubleshooting if you disable the spark logs. You may want to give it a thought.

Yeah, we can do that but that does not save your operations cost, which comes when you write into gcs bucket. We want to enable them when we need it
